# permissions differ in single and multi user modes

Tags: solaris-10

file permission for /home when seen from multi user mode is r-xr-xr-x but when logged in as single user mode it shows as rwxr-xr-x Please any one can help in this case

Answer (score 1):

When you go multi-user, another partition is mounted or auto-mounted on top of /home.  Anything in your root partition's /home directory is unavailable when multi-user.

/home has two different disk directories mounted at the two different run levels; there is no reason for them to have any correlation to one another.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem?

When you log-in in single user mode, the permissions change to reflect it.

Execute permission is required for you to `cd` into a directory.

If you're the only user (and probably there to repair something) why not?